# Trying to use the browser to initiate an outbound call to customer and agent

Tags: twilio, twilio-javascript

I am trying to initiate a call from a button click in the browser using the Twilio Voice JS SDK (v.2.1.1).

I have successfully created the voice object (`this.voice`), and when I run the code below, I am receiving an error in the browser console, "`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`".

The code I'm using was demonstrated at https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls/node.

NOTE: When I run this same code in the C# implementation, it works as expected.

Here is my code:
@lizziepika, here are the applicable code snips related to this issue:

```
bindVoice() : void {
  this.tcemsService.getVoiceCapabilityToken().toPromise().then
  (
    voiceToken => {
      this.voice = new Twilio.Device( voiceToken.token, {
        disableAudioContextSounds: true
      } );
    }
  )
}
```

... then ...

```
_this.bindVoice();
_this.voice.create( {
  twiml: '<Say>Connecting Call</Say>',
  to: '+14071234567',
  from: '+14079876543'
} );
```

When I set a breakpoint, `_this.voice` exists, but the method for create fails.

Comment: Can you include the complete code that returns the error?

Comment: @lizziepika, The code in the original post has been edited to include all applicable code for this issue.